# Unable to compile Rust from x86_64-redhat-linux to aarch64-linux-gnu

Tags: linux, gcc, rust, raspberry-pi

I am trying to compile a simple binary for my Raspberry Pi 4, running a 64 bit of Raspberry Pi OS. I installed the appropriate Rust tool-chain using this command:

```
rustup target install aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

This command succeeded, and then I proceeded to install the appropriate C compiler for this platform with this command:

```
sudo dnf install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
```

This installed gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu, binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu cross-binutils-common, cross-gcc-common, gmp-c++, gmp-devel, isl, libmpc-devel, and mpfr-devel.

I then tried to build my crate with the appropriate command, and ended up with this error:

```
cargo build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
   Compiling rpi-lights v0.1.0 (/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/home/mfrodiguez/.cargo/bin:/home/mfrodiguez/.local/bin:/home/mfrodiguez/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin" VSLANG="1033" "cc" "/tmp/rustcuAfmEP/symbols.o" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.2l7b2zzvnvj2nrri.rcgu.o" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.2nr37zcssf70uhel.rcgu.o" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.2sdthdq114ippsaq.rcgu.o" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.3qeqr4ok7jpxpy9c.rcgu.o" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.41ee08lom32zupep.rcgu.o" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.fve3upvf6ey7fub.rcgu.o" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.3sgxewh3axgx080d.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-f332c29dd80c3c82.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-8284b54cb3181ab5.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-95228d4729b96bfd.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libmemchr-33f3012c2a5cbbf6.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-48c503623e5575a4.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-569c825e9b63260b.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-1932015da4782d6f.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-fde550d8b94c714c.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-badd4f89626baa84.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-0f995432aa76f3ae.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-bf6de27a2226f775.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-a3326a257f5cb8f1.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-fe57e61c90cbd018.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-cb0f4a07ecbd24ca.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-575b3f5321243553.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-657a92792869e75f.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-23dbd14d61b34954.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-38c2d9d4d5404a1a.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-25887170a022cc00.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-L" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: /home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.2l7b2zzvnvj2nrri.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.2l7b2zzvnvj2nrri.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.2l7b2zzvnvj2nrri.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.2l7b2zzvnvj2nrri.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.2l7b2zzvnvj2nrri.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.2l7b2zzvnvj2nrri.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.2l7b2zzvnvj2nrri.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.2l7b2zzvnvj2nrri.rcgu.o: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I presumed this was a linker error, and specified the appropriate linker, to which I got this result:

```
cargo build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
   Compiling rpi-lights v0.1.0 (/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights)
error: linking with `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/home/mfrodiguez/.cargo/bin:/home/mfrodiguez/.local/bin:/home/mfrodiguez/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin" VSLANG="1033" "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "/tmp/rustcy0cTq2/symbols.o" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.2l7b2zzvnvj2nrri.rcgu.o" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.2nr37zcssf70uhel.rcgu.o" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.2sdthdq114ippsaq.rcgu.o" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.3qeqr4ok7jpxpy9c.rcgu.o" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.41ee08lom32zupep.rcgu.o" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.fve3upvf6ey7fub.rcgu.o" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe.3sgxewh3axgx080d.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-f332c29dd80c3c82.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-8284b54cb3181ab5.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-95228d4729b96bfd.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libmemchr-33f3012c2a5cbbf6.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-48c503623e5575a4.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-569c825e9b63260b.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-1932015da4782d6f.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-fde550d8b94c714c.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-badd4f89626baa84.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-0f995432aa76f3ae.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-bf6de27a2226f775.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-a3326a257f5cb8f1.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-fe57e61c90cbd018.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-cb0f4a07ecbd24ca.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-575b3f5321243553.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-657a92792869e75f.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-23dbd14d61b34954.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-38c2d9d4d5404a1a.rlib" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-25887170a022cc00.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-L" "/home/mfrodiguez/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/home/mfrodiguez/Projects/rpi-lights/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/deps/rpi_lights-6a6c4c0d022f9bbe" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lutil: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lrt: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lpthread: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lm: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -ldl: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lc: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          

error: could not compile `rpi-lights` (bin "rpi-lights") due to previous error
```

I am now unsure of what to do to get a successful compilation.

Comment: The same trick you're trying works [on debian](https://old.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/11sq4wj/was_crosscompiling_and_crossrunning_tests_always/?ref=share&ref_source=link). Maybe you could try compiling for `aarch64-unknown-linux-musl` by setting `linker = "/usr/bin/clang"` `rustflags = ["-C", "link-arg=--ld-path=/usr/bin/ld.lld", "-C", "link-arg=--target=aarch64-unknown-linux-musl"]`. `rustup target add` should bring in all the necessary libs for that.